# About modify spring boot 1.5.3 to support recognise jsp files

Tags: jsp, tomcat, spring-boot

I used spring boot + jsp, and from [this post](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/boot-serve-dynamic/) I know if put jsp files in `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/` also could package as a executable jar.

Unfortunately when I modify spring boot version from `1.4.2` to `1.5.3`, it cannot support and return 404. After hours tracing their source codes and compare I know why `1.5.3` cannot support it.

`Spring boot 1.4.2`

```
//org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.StoreMergedWebXmlListener#onStart
private void onStart(Context context) {
    ServletContext servletContext = context.getServletContext();
    if(servletContext.getAttribute("org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.MergedWebXml") == null) {
        servletContext.setAttribute("org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.MergedWebXml", this.getEmptyWebXml());
    }
    // only 1.4.2 has this line and with this code could recognise jsp files in /META-INF/resources/
    TomcatResources.get(context).addClasspathResources(); 
}
```

Spring boot 1.5.3

```
private void onStart(Context context) {
    ServletContext servletContext = context.getServletContext();
    if (servletContext.getAttribute(MERGED_WEB_XML) == null) {
        servletContext.setAttribute(MERGED_WEB_XML, getEmptyWebXml());
    }
}
```

So I want to know why after 1.4.2 have to remove this code?

```
TomcatResources.get(context).addClasspathResources();
```

And because I still want to use 1.5.3 so I have to manually add this code by below way

1.copy source code of `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` to current classpath 
[image]

2.do below modify

```
private void onStart(Context context) {
    ServletContext servletContext = context.getServletContext();
    if (servletContext.getAttribute(MERGED_WEB_XML) == null) {
        servletContext.setAttribute(MERGED_WEB_XML, getEmptyWebXml());
    }
    // Add below code
    ClassLoader loader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    URL[] urLs = ((URLClassLoader) loader).getURLs();
    List<URL> list = new ArrayList<>();
    //String file = "file:/Users/zhugw/workspace/boot-jar-serving-jsp/boot-jar-serving-jsp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/";
    String file = urLs[0].getFile().replaceFirst("BOOT-INF/classes!/", "");
    URL jar = new URL("jar", "", file);
    list.add(0,jar);
    TomcatResources.get(context).addResourceJars(list);
}
```

and it does works. And I want to know if could do this so?

Answer (score 1):

We have the same pb here.

1. We tried your solution but unsuccessfully. The following exception was raised when starting the application :

> ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TldSkipPatterns from
>   class
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory
>         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:130)
>
> ...

2. Finally it seems the call to "TomcatResources.get(context).addClasspathResources();" has not been removed but refactored.

Now in SpringBoot 1.5.8.RELEASE, you have the following lines in TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.prepareContext():

```
context.addLifecycleListener(new LifecycleListener() {
    @Override
    public void lifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent event) {
        if (event.getType().equals(Lifecycle.CONFIGURE_START_EVENT)) {
            TomcatResources.get(context)
                    .addResourceJars(getUrlsOfJarsWithMetaInfResources());
        }
    }
});
```

3. In our case, we were using a customized EmbeddedServletContainerFactory (override of some methods of TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) and for an unknown reason, the classloader retrieved in getUrlOfJarsWithMetaInfResources() was almost empty (only the classes folder with no jar file).

Solution: We've simply removed this override. Jar files areback in the classloader and consequently jsp files stored in those jar files are now correctly recognized by the app.

Comment: but I think you could do this workaround for legacy project, but if it is a new project I suggest you to use more advanced template engine, e.g `Thymeleaf`  and I feel the cost learning is not very high.